# Necessary condition for the existence of subobject classifier

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I was reading the article on subobject classifiers on

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject+classifier

Well, in Section 6 the author writes: " there is an easy condition ensuring a category with a terminal object can’t have a subobject classifier: if there are no nonidentity morphisms out of the terminal object".

I do not understand the formal meaning of the necessary condition. Can you help me, please?

Comment: "ensures" means "sufficient", not "necessary". You're asking (based on the accepted answer) about the condition being sufficient :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're thinking too hard about this.

Remember how the subobject classifier $\Omega$ is defined! It says that every mono in your category is a pullback of one ~special mono~ $\mathsf{True} : 1 \rightarrowtail \Omega$.

But if there *aren't* any monos out of $1$, then there's no ~special mono~ out of $1$ either, and a subobject classifier cannot exist!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Well, unless $\Omega = 1$ and $\mathsf{True} = \text{id}_1$. This implies that every object has a unique subobject, so every mono in the category is an isomorphism. If what the nLab says is correct, this + finite limits should imply that every object is terminal. But I don't immediately see why.

Comment: Oh, I got it: Suppose there are two arrows $f,g\colon X\to Y$. Their equalizer is monic, so it's an isomorphism,  so $f = g$. But then the category is a preorder, so every arrow in the category is trivially monic, hence an isomorphism. Since every object maps to the terminal object, every  object is terminal.